# Print specific image size in galley loop

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I have the below loop and would like to print a specific thumbnail size, as this loop currently prints the full size image. How would I print a smaller thumbnail?

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
endwhile; // end of the loop. 

$rows = get_field( 'gallery' );
if ( $rows ) { 
    ?><ul id="galleryList" class="fullWidth"><?php 
    foreach( $rows as $row ) { 
        ?><li class="galleryBox">
            <a href="<?php echo $row['link_to_gallery']; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">
            </a>
        </li><?php 
    } 
    ?></ul><?php 
} // endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own [post thumbnail sizes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size)

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 );
```

This means that you change the thumbnail size overall.

Or you can [define custom image sizes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_theme_setup' );
function wpdocs_theme_setup() {
    add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 300 ); // 300 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
    add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180, true ); // (cropped)
}
```

and call it like:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumb' ); 
}
```

Comment: So would the code be: '<a href="<?php echo $row['link_to_gallery']; ?>">
                <img src="if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumb' ); 
}">
            </a>'

Comment: Remember to enclose `php code` into `<?php ?>` and then call it like `<a href="<?php echo $row['link_to_gallery']; ?>"> <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumb' ); } ?> </a>`